# How can I serve static content and spring data rest at / using content negotiation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I would like to host both static content, and spring data rest  on `/`

```
curl http://localhost:8080                                                                                                                                       slave-vi
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>RPF</title><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"><base href="/"><link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet"></head><body aurelia-app="main"><div class="splash"><div class="message">RPF</div><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></div><script type="text/javascript" src="aurelia-bootstrap.3c6271fc099630981613.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="aurelia.042f8d07b45053bfe6a6.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="app.86af2df503886ba0a486.bundle.js"></script></body></html>
```

where the only difference should be based on on content negotiation

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json" http://localhost:8080                                                                                                    slave-vi
{
  "_links" : {
    "users" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/users{?page,size,sort}",
      "templated" : true
    },
    "profile" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/profile"
    }
  }
}
```

So if browser `Accept` headers (they're kind of non specific) or no accept headers are sent, I'd get the `index.html` but if `application/json` or other specific content headers are sent I'd get that type or a 415 depending on supportedness.

currently I set static locations by adding this on the command line `-Dspring.resources.staticLocations=...`

Answer (score 0):

You could have a Controller listen for all requests on `/` and forward them based on some condition:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public String handleIndexPage(@RequestHeader(value="Accept") String acceptValue) {
    if (MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE.equals(acceptValue)) {
        return "forward:/spring-data-rest-url";
    } else {
        return "forward:/other-url";
    }
}
```

Comment: possible. I had forgotten I asked this, but it's become an accepted bug https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6668, that said this could be a valid workaround.